# System.BadImageFormatException Prism7 WPF Windows 10 Client

Tags: wpf, prism

I created a simple Prism WPF Application. In my development environment it runs without error. When I install it on a Windows 10 machine and try to run the application I get a System.BadImageFormatException.

I then created a blank prism 7 application, and installed that on the Windows 10 machine and it gives the same error. No other Nuget packages were installed, pure, plain simple application.

I also tried changing the application to x86, and then to x64 and back to Any CPU. But I get the same error. I have installed it on a different Windows 10 machine and the error persists. Again, in development it runs 100%.

Eventviewer error:
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.BadImageFormatException

```
Exception Info: System.BadImageFormatException
   at Prism.Unity.PrismApplication.CreateContainerExtension()
   at Prism.PrismApplicationBase.Initialize()
   at Prism.PrismApplicationBase.InitializeInternal()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at YouTubeDownloader.App.Main()
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is usually a x64 vs x86 issue, but can't think of what might trigger that in a empty application.  When you are switching to x64, is the "prefer 32 bit" still selected.  That is if you are using Visual Studio.

Comment: @RobGoodwin Sorry for the delayed response. No, I made sure that the prefer 32 bit is not ticked when switching to x64.